# Flipcard CSS 3D Transition: solution for compatibility IE / Opera?

Tags: javascript, css, compatibility, transformation, modernizr

I love the css flipcard transformation they did at premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-a-wordpress-post-list-wonderwall-the-card-flipper/ (concept from queness). So I adapted it on my site (it looks great), but I really have trouble adapting it for cross-browser-compatibility. (IE and Opera are not displaying it right according to browserstack).

**Can anybody help me tweak the code that it is replaced on browsers where it cannot run and runs on all browsers that support 3D CSS transformations?** That would be a great help!

The guys at [brainstormforce](https://www.brainstormforce.com/demos/ultimate/flip-box/) have done it quite well in their flipcard plugin. But I can´t spot the solution for my implementation...

You find my code in a jsfiddle - slightly cleaned, just to see the function working: http://jsfiddle.net/X49EK/

HTML: in jsfiddle

The CSS:

```
    .thumb {
    /* display:block; - to be able to use display:hidden in parent for responsiveness */
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    }

    .thumb-wrapper {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }

    /* Front */
    .thumb .thumb-front {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    background:#ff3030;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-color:#ffffff;
    padding-top:50px;
    }

    /* Back */
    .thumb .thumb-detail {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolut;
    background:#ffffff;
    left:0;
    top:0;

    border-width:1px; !important;
    border-color:#ff6600; !important;
    border-style:solid;
    padding:15px;
    }

    /* Back Header */
    .thumb .thumb-detail-header {
    font-size: 16px;!important;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    text-align:left;
    }

    /* Back Text */
    .thumb .thumb-detail, .thumb .thumb-detail p {
    font-size: 13px;!important;
    color: #595959;!important;
    line-height: 1.4em;!important;
    text-align:justify;   
    }


    /*
    * Without CSS3
    */
    .thumb.scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    .thumb.scroll .thumb-detail {
    bottom:-400px;
    }

    /*
    * CSS3 Flip
    */
    .thumb.flip {
    -webkit-perspective:800px;
    -moz-perspective:800px;
    -ms-perspective:800px;
    -o-perspective:800px;
    perspective:800px;
    }

    .thumb.flip .thumb-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -ms-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    .thumb.flip .thumb-detail {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }

    .thumb.flip .thumb-front,
    .thumb.flip .thumb-detail {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    .thumb.flip .flipIt {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
```

The Javascript (for cross-browser compatibility, uses Modernizr):

```
$(function () {


    if ($('html').hasClass('csstransforms3d')) {    

        $('.thumb').removeClass('scroll').addClass('flip');     
        $('.thumb.flip').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').addClass('flipIt');
            },
            function () {
                $(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').removeClass('flipIt');           
            }
        );

    } else {

        $('.thumb').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).find('.thumb-detail').stop().animate({bottom:0}, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
            },
            function () {
                $(this).find('.thumb-detail').stop().animate({bottom: ($(this).height() * -1) }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');          
            }
        );

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/YHeKX/306/)**

The `backface-visibility` property relates to 3D transforms.
Firefox 10+ and IE 10+ support backface-visibility with no prefix. Opera (post Blink, 15+), Chrome, Safari, iOS, and Android all need -webkit-backface-visibility.

Values

`visible` (default) - will always be visible even when not facing the screen.

`hidden` - not visible when not facing the screen.

`inherit` - gets its value from the its parent element.

`initial` - sets the property to its default, which is visible.

For more information [Flip card effect for non-webkit browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268428/flip-card-effect-for-non-webkit-browsers)   &   [CSS3 - 3D Flip Animation - IE10 transform-origin: preserve-3d workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474210/css3-3d-flip-animation-ie10-transform-origin-preserve-3d-workaround)

Comment: Linked demo is not IE10 or 11 compatible, only shows front face in reverse.